# Can we install two different android studio versions in same windows machine?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1, android-update-sdk

I have android studio version 2.1.3 installed. But i want to update it to latest version of android studio. And when i update it gives me following error[image]

So is any way to install another version in to same machine??

Comment: Are you running on administrator ? can you try with local user ?

Comment: yes as a administrator. No not yet with local user

Comment: Try with local user then update it, it will work.